# How to dispatch a new message in a dynamically loaded button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to dispatch a message whenever I change a room - which load dynamically,
I have a component that looks like that:

```
const Rooms = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className='rooms-styles'>
        {rooms.length === 0 && <p>This server is missing rooms!! WERE GOING TO DIEEE!!</p>}
              <div>
                  {rooms.length > 0 && rooms.map((roomBtn)=><button onClick={()=>{/* Need to dispatch here! */}}>{roomBtn.roomName}</button>)}
             </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and I'm trying to change a state property (that's how it's called?) called 'room'.

### What I've tried so far:

- set a mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps like that:

`selectedRoom` is the selected room, being set at the button click as `selectedRoom = roomBtn.roomName`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      room: selectedRoom
    };
  };
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({changeRoom}, dispatch);
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps ,mapDispatchToProps)(Rooms);
```

- use `props.dispatch(changeRoom(roomBtn.roomName))` when `changeRoom` is an action (didn't work because I don't have access to `props` inside `onClick`)

github page: https://github.com/Ido-Levi/Playground

Comment: with the arrow operator, you will have access to the props inside the onClick function

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? props is undefined??

Comment: already tried that, props is undefined

Comment: oh, sorry - I'm getting `e.dispatch is not a function`

Comment: in your `mapStateToProps` function you forgot to use the state argument. `room: state.selectedRoom`

Comment: @Benjamin I don't have a `selectedRoom` property on the state, `selectedRoom` is a global variable of the Room component

Comment: @IdoHLevi "selectedRoom is a global variable of the Room component"

Then why is it in mapStateToProps? Why not just use selectedRoom inside the Room component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the `mapDispatchToProps` function
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

You must return an object which will have the key that is the prop to the component

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {changeRoomDispatch : bindActionCreators({changeRoom}, dispatch)};
  };
```

and then use `onClick={() => props.changeRoomDispatch(roomBtn.roomName)}`

**Alternatively**

you can use connect without the second argument for `mapDispatchToProps` as

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Rooms);
```

and have access to the `dispatch` prop inside the function and then `onClick={() => props.dispatch(changeRoom(roomBtn.roomName))}` should work fine.

refer the link above for documentation

Comment: as what should I define `changeRoomDispatch`? (otherwise it says its undefined), and I still can't access `props.dispatch` from inside the onClick

Comment: btw, this is the github page for this project https://github.com/Ido-Levi/Playground

Comment: @IdoHLevi You cannot access props.dispatch since it is mapped to the key changeRoomDispatch. you can use props.changeRoomDispatch to run the dispatcher.

Comment: if you need props.dispatch, then use the second approach.